# AS3 - Dictionary objects allocated by a simple dictionary[key]=value call

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dictionary, adobe-scout

While profiling my app in Scout I noticed it shows that the method **JSONObject.internalPut** is responsible for allocating 2,355 Dictionary objects.

The method's code is as follows:

```
internal function internalPut(key:String, value:*):void {
    _map[key] = value;  // _map is a Dictionary 
}
```

How can we explain this?

**_map** is a Dictionary object created in JSONObject's constructor **without** the weakKeys parameter (i.e. it's false)

Can a simple dictionary[key]=value allocate anything??

Thanks for any help

Eyal

[image: Scout shows that internalPut method allocated 2,355 Dictionary Objects]

Comment: are your values primitive types?

Comment: Not only - beside primitives, I also put in that map two objects of type JSONObject and JSONArray... can it matter?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that in Flash/AS3, empty Dictionary or Array objects may internally create another instance of their own class during first object assignment, that is when the first 'put' operation on a Dictionary occurs, or the first 'push' command on an Array occurs.

From what I investigated, this will only happen when these collection objects were cleared before (i.e. they had values and then emptied via their 'delete' or 'splice' calls)

Hope it helps,

Eyal